# CSS3 keep background color transitions the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Various elements of the webpage have a background transition on them changing from color to color:

```
@-moz-keyframes backgroundTransition /* Firefox */ {
    0%   {background-color:#ff7b7b;}
    33%   {background-color:#7fceff;}
    66%   {background-color:#80e880;}
    100%   {background-color:#ff7b7b;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes backgroundTransition /* Safari and Chrome */{
    0%   {background-color:#ff7b7b;}
    33%   {background-color:#7fceff;}
    66%   {background-color:#80e880;}
    100%   {background-color:#ff7b7b;}
}
```

However, if an element is `display: none` and then displayed later through javascript, the color isn't consistent with the other elements, it starts the loop from the `0%` color.

Is there a way to keep the transition universal? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried hiding the elements by making their `opacity:0` and then setting it to `1` to unhide them? That should allow the background color to transition with all the other elements, but keep the element invisible.

Byh the way, the `keyframes` CSS directive is well supported by all major browsers at this point. There is no longer a need to use vendor prefixes with it.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.querySelector(".hidden").classList.remove("hidden");
});
```

```css
div {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:black;
  border:1px solid black;
  
  animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-name: backgroundTransition;
}

/* The hidden elements will not take up space in the
   normal document flow and will not be visible because
   the will be 100% transparent. Simply removing this 
   class when its time to see the element(s) puts them
   back into the normal flow and their background will
   be the same as all the other div elements. */
.hidden { opacity:0; position:absolute; }

@keyframes backgroundTransition{
 0%   {background-color:#ff7b7b;}
  33%   {background-color:#7fceff;}
  66%   {background-color:#80e880;}
  100%   {background-color:#ff7b7b;}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div class="hidden"></div>
<div></div>

<button>Click me during the animation to reveal the hidden div,<br>which will have its color in sync with the other div elements</button>
```

Comment: I need the display to be none for responsive purposes. Could this be achieved with JS?

Comment: @SSAM Do you? If the element was `position:absolute`, it would not take up any space within the normal flow of the document. See my updated answer that does this.

Comment: Perfect. I did not know that would work the same. Thank you Scott

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can handle it using visibility css attribute or you cant cuz whenever it gets rendered it will start from 0

Answer (score 0):

Transitions didn't work for element not rendered by browser, but work's for element 'hided' ;) try antoher option to hide your element:

`opacity: 0`

`height:0; width:0;`

`z-index: <val>`